# XCode 6 switch control doesn't update size

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout, constraints

This might be an error from my part but I have a very strange issue: I set up a switch that is proportional with the parent view, that is proportional with the window. 
 All looking fine in preview mode, the switch is actually changing proportions based on the screen it is rendered. 
 However, when you run it in simulator, all this magic goes away, the switch is back to it's big size again, same size on all displays...
 Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You should show us your code/storyboard settings

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell... Maybe check on your storyboard constraints relations (equal / greater than or equal etc...)
Or you can always subclass your switch button and set his size from there :)

If you can provide us more info it would help a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because `UISwitch` inherits from `UIControl` that sizes itself, so you should subclass it and implement these methods:

- `- (void)sizeToFit`
- `- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size`
- `- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize`

It should work this way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will give it a go, but I thought that just by using constraints it should take care of the coding, specifically since in preview mode they seem to have the correct size (and centering) reported to the parent view. Everything looks bad only in simulator and, usually, what you see in preview is what you see in simulator.